# Why Did Data's Eyes Get More Yellow?

Tags: star-trek

I've noticed that Data's eyes got more yellow in Insurrection than they were in the series, or the other movies. Is there a reason for the darker shade in color?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Flanderization](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Flanderization)?

Comment: Hmm, it's possible

Comment: Out of Universe, probably because they didn't have or couldn't get, or Spiner/Frakes didn't want the same contact lenses as in the series.

Comment: Or it just looks more yellow in those particular photos. Colour reproduction, and colour in general, is super-complex: see [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1882/) and [A Smart Bear](https://blog.asmartbear.com/color-wheels.html).

Comment: He's a Sith Lord?

Comment: It might be that they're not more yellow, but instead have smaller pupils

Comment: I see no evidence the premise is accurate.   Color and perception of color are heavily affected by lighting, camera/film technology, and any number of things.   It certainly doesn't look like it's the case between these two pictures -- it's just that one is in daylight which can be thousands to millions of times brighter indoors.

Comment: Assuming for the sake of argument that the premise is correct, the out-of-universe intent might have been to make him look more threatening during the "rogue android" scenes.  In-universe one might suppose that the same attack that caused Data's malfunction also changed the colour of his eyes.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's the difference of movie quality equipment and film stock versus TV quality. You'll notice that in the movies, the gold color they always used for Brent Spiner's makeup also looks more actually like the pale gold they used than the footage in the TV show, which made it look like it was plain white.  But it was definitely always the same gold color in reality.

Comment: The small pupils definitely make him look more menacing.

Comment: @Kai. Yeah, I guess that's true, but he looks the same in Generations and First Contact as in the series.

Comment: Holy-- guys, it's Mystique!

Comment: Wait!  Why did his hairline get higher and his forehead and neck get wrinklier??

Answer (score 7):

In this image from the same movie Data's eyes look more like they did during the TNG television series.

[image]

I would conclude that where they look more yellow it is simply a result of the lighting in the scene and different film/cinematography/post-processing in the movie. The movies in general have a different look to a typical TNG episode.

Comment: I agree. The Films tended to "dress up" things a little more elegantly than the tv series did. You have a single "mega-episode" with a higher budget vs a smaller hour-long episode with the budget a tv series would have. Thus that equals: nicer clothing, nicer props, nicer make-up jobs, nicer sets, nicer effects, etc.